# CS231N Lecture 4 Back Prop - Chain Rule

Tags: backpropagation

I am sure this has a simple answer! I am asking to improve my understanding.

A diagram: a modification of: [CS231N Back Propagation](http://cs231n.stanford.edu/slides/2016/winter1516_lecture4.pdf)
[image: Back Propagation Through Time]

If the Cain Rule is applied to get the Delta for Y, the Gradient will be: `dy = -4` according to the Diagram.

Applying Chain Rule Notation: `df/dy = df/dq * dq/dy`

Numerically:

```
double x = -2;
double y = 5; 
double q = 3;
double z = -4;
double f = -12;

double df = 1;
double dz = 3;
double dq = -4;
double dy = df * dq; 
double dx = df * dq;
```

Where: `df = df/df = 1` as shown above, and `dq = df/dq = -4` as shown above. Thus: `1(df) * -4(dq) = -4(dy)`. Or have I got this completely wrong?

Where are the Numerical Values actually coming from, where in the diagram? Is this a Gradient Only Numerical chain or are we deriving from the other input values? The reason I ask here, is because on Page 48, there is a slightly confusing Code Example:
[image]

I am looking at the (/) sign, `df/dy`, as a division, and I think this is wrong? `df/dy = df/dq * dq/dy` = `1/-4 * -4/-4` = 0.25 - What is the purpose of one number over the other here?

Is it that `df/dy` = `dy` are they the same things, symbolising `dy` of `df`, meaning one Gradient Flowing Back in Time?

Apologies, I am somewhat confused.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A refresher on Differential Equations helped clear up the confusion: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/differential-equations/first-order-differential-equations/differential-equations-intro/v/differential-equation-introduction

Confusion is the greatest problem for learning!